# Access a value from a Kotlin script using jsr-223

Tags: kotlin, jsr223

I'm wondering if it's possible to access variables from a kotlin script using jsr-223

```
with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!) {
        eval("val x = 3")
        val x = get("x")
        println(x) <---------- x is null
    }
```

Here I want to access the variable x, but it seems to evalute to null.

Is there another way to access data from within the script?

I have looked at some examples here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example
but I can't seem to find what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by creating a function that returns the value, and calling that function.

```
with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!) {
        eval("fun getX() = 3")
        val invocator = this as? Invocable
        val x = invocator!!.invokeFunction("getX")
        println(x) <---------- x is 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: `eval` returns the result of last expression executed.

```
with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!) {
        val x = eval("1 + 2")
        println(x) <---------- x is 3
}
```